# Installing a packaged Django app results in failed "migrate" error "no module named..."

Tags: django, nginx, virtualenv, pythonpath, python-packaging

**Ubuntu 16.04 LTS • nginx 1.10.0 • Python 2.7.12 • Django-1.10.5**

I've completed the tutorials at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/, which are all built using virtualenv

**To learn to package up my app and reuse it,** I am following the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/ which does not use virtualenv, but **I can't get it to work**.

**The app is called "polls". Here is what I did to create the package:**

1. Removed all the .pyc files left in my app
2. pip install setuptools & sudo pip install django
3. moved my (correctly functioning) app directory from the project directory to my home directory

   ~$ mv -rfp example/polls django-polls
4. in the new "django-polls" folder I created **README.rst**, **LICENSE**, and modified **setup.py**, by

commenting out:

```
\#'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
\#'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
\#'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
```

5. created **MANIFEST.in** (no documentation)
6. built the package, with no issues: **python setup.py sdist**

**So far everything seemed to be working correctly.**

## I want to re-use my application at a different site, but I cannot complete the migration after installing it.

I install the new package with no apparent issues:

```
pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

To finish the installation, I:

1. **add 'polls' to INSTALLED_APPS** in settings.py, in a different site/project folder
2. modify **urls.py** by adding

   url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
3. **python manage.py migrate**

## NOW I GET AN ERROR:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
```

I thought: perhaps because I installed polls with the --user flag, it is not available to the virtualenv, so I "workon" the virtualenv and re-install polls:

```
pip install django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
```

It goes fine, but I get the same error when I try to migrate:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
```

So, I can't get my app to work from within the virtualenv.

To get the path for polls, I type:

```
pip uninstall polls
```

and get "Cannot uninstall requirement polls, not installed"

**The result is the same if I am in the virtualenv or if I have deactivated it.**

To check the install locations, I tried reinstalling the app with and without the virtualenv and get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Env/myenvironment/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

So the app is installed both within the virtualenv and outside of it, but it is missing either way when I do the migrate.

I have spent the whole day trying various variations of paths and other similar tutorials but cannot get past this point.

Answer (score 1):

When I created the application according to the tutorial, I moved all my working app files into the new application folder, *not* keeping them in their folder (**~$ mv -rfp example/polls django-polls** in the question above).

In other words, I had moved the contents of:

```
~/sitename/polls
```

directly to:

```
~/django-polls
```

when I should have moved it to:

```
~/django-polls/polls
```

This was wrong, and I needed to keep everything in the folder:

```
~$ cd ~/django-polls
~$ mv -f ../sitename/polls ./
```

Finally, to get the app to work I needed to **install the app while working in the virtualenv,** without the --user flag.